# Reading Microsoft Access files in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, ms-jet-ace

How to read (and write) MS Access files (.mdb) in Java?
Is there any open-source jdbc driver for MS Access?

Comment: MDF is not a common Jet file extension.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the open source [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) library to read an Access database through Java (currently supporting Access versions 2000-2007).

Comment: Jackcess is good, but it only works for Access 2000 (JET4) files.

Comment: @Yuval: Thanks, I edited my answer to include that information.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard can you update this entry? Jackcess now supports Access 2000 through 2007.

Comment: Saying that it supports A2007 raises the question of whether it supports A2010. Very little of the data format changed, but A2010 introduced table-level data macros (which can be used to implement triggers), and that's a significant change.

Comment: @David: I don't have Access 2010 to test with, but I imagine they'd claim support if it worked, so probably not.

Comment: jackcess now supports access 2010 (although it doesn't support macros).